# Shorter case statement

Tags: ruby, case

Let's take in consideration this ruby code:

```
@name = case @name
  when 1 then "Noah"
  when 2 then "Liam"
  when 3 then "Mason"
  when 4 then "Jacob"
  when 5 then "William"
  when 6 then "Ethan"
  when 7 then "James"
  when 8 then "Alexander"
  when 9 then "Michael"
  when 10 then "Benjamin"
  when 11 then "Elijah"
  when 12 then "Daniel"
  when 13 then "Aiden"
  when 14 then "Logan"
  when 15 then "Matthew"
  when 16 then "Lucas"
  when 17 then "Jackson"
  when 18 then "David"
  when 19 then "Oliver"
  when 20 then "Jayden"
  when 21 then "Joseph"
  when 22 then "Gabriel"
  when 23 then "Samuel"
  when 24 then "Carter"
  when 25 then "Anthony"
  when 26 then "John"
  when 27 then "Dylan"
  when 28 then "Luke"
  when 29 then "Henry"
  when 30 then "Andrew"
end
```

I have the strong suspect that there is a much shorter way to write the same thing. Something in the shape of `@name.case["Noah", "Liam"...]`. Even LaTeX has a better way to handle this. Consider that my program will have a very long list of case statements like that so if I leave it like that it might work, but it'll be extremely long and difficult to read. I can't find anything like that though.

Do you know if there is such an option?

Comment: While the answers are correct. You may want to also consider storing the names in a parsable file to avoid cluttering up your code base. I would recommend `YAML` then the list of names would just be `@all_names = YAML.load('your_names_file.yml')`

Comment: @engineersmnky, why do you suggest YAML rather than simply `File.readlines(filename).map(&:chomp)`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland in the event that the OP opts for `Hash` at any point the code base does not need to change very much if at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numeric values of `@name` are consecutive values starting with `0` (or `1`), a simple array that contains all the values should be enough:

```
@name = ['', 'Noah', 'Liam', 'Mason', 'Jacob', 'William'][@name]
```

Fill free to put as many names as you want after `'William'`.

If the keys are not consecutive or they are not integer numbers then a [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html) can be used instead:

```
 @name = { '1': 'Noah', 'three': 'Mason', '5': 'William' }[@name.to_s.to_sym]
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have your list of `names`. You could create an hash that map integers to them

```
mapping = Hash[(1..names.size).zip(names)]
```

then implement a function that given a number and the mapping rules returns a name or something else

```
def id_to_name(id, mapping)
  mapping.fetch(id, 'no name')
end
```

You could even make a class for this, so this method does not need the mapping as parameter

```
class IdToName
  def initialize(names, fallback_name)
    @mapping = Hash[(1..names.size).zip(names)]
    @fallback_name = fallback_name
  end

  def get(id)
    @mapping.fetch(id, @fallback_name)
  end
end

id_to_name = IdToName.new(your_names, 'no name')
puts id_to_name.get(1) # Noah
puts id_to_name.get(1000) # no name
```

Comment: I didn't think about the hash but it made indeed sense. In the end though I found that for this particular scenario it was better to just use an array as advised below

Answer (score 2):

The shortest possible way is to create an array using the `%w` shortcut to eliminate extraneous punctuation:

```
names = %w(Noah   Liam    Mason  Jacob  William Ethan James   Alexander Michael Benjamin
           Elijah Daniel  Aiden  Logan  Matthew Lucas Jackson David     Oliver  Jayden 
           Joseph Gabriel Samuel Carter Anthony John  Dylan   Luke      Henry   Andrew)
```

You can add line breaks, extra spaces, etc. Then simply index them using @name:

```
names[@name - 1]
```

Since the first element of `names` is 0, you have to subtract one from `@name` or put a dummy element in the beginning so you can start at 1.